# Residue theorem /Integral

Tags: improper-integrals, residue-calculus, rational-functions

I want to calculate the following integral using residue theorem:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{x^4+1} $$
When I conisder the singularities, I get:

$ \text{Rez}(f, z_k)=\frac{1}{4z_k}$ with $z_k=e^{i \pi (\frac{2k+1}{4})} $
I only have to consider $k=0$ and $k=1$. 
But when I put that in my formula, I only get something not real.
Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Don't forget to multiply the sum of the residues by $2\pi i$

Comment: Yes, but how can I put this together  $e^{-i \pi/4} +  e^{-i \pi (\frac{3}{4})} $

Comment: Don't you have to add them all up (as in residue theorem), there is probably cancellation

Comment: Yes, I was editing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z_0$ is a zero of $z^4+1$, then$$\operatorname{res}_{z=z_0}\frac{z^2}{z^4+1}=\frac{{z_0}^2}{4{z_0}^3}=\frac1{4z_0}.$$You are right: you only have to consider the cases $z_0=\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}4\right)$ and $z_0=\exp\left(\frac{3\pi i}4\right)$. So\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2}{x^4+1}\,\mathrm dx&=2\pi i\left(\frac1{4\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}4\right)}+\frac1{4\exp\left(\frac{3\pi i}4\right)}\right)\\&=\frac{\pi i}2\left(\exp\left(-\frac{\pi i}4\right)+\exp\left(-\frac{3\pi i}4\right)\right)\\&=\frac{\pi i}2\times\left(-\sqrt2i\right)\\&=\frac\pi{\sqrt2}.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you.I dont get how you calculate exp.... I get $cos(\pi/4) +cos(3 \pi /4) -i(sin(\pi/4) + sin(3\pi/4))$

Comment: Do you mean $\exp\left(-\frac{\pi i}4\right)$ and $\exp\left(-\frac{3\pi i}4\right)$?

Comment: @SvenMath $\exp(i\theta) = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$

Comment: Yes. Sorry.I accidentaly push the add comment button before I finish  my answer.

Comment: Well, meanwhile @MoonKnight provided the answer.

Comment: I know the euler formula...My first comment was a bit further.

Comment: Well, $\exp\left(-\frac{\pi i}4\right)=\cos\left(-\frac{\pi i}4\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac{\pi i}4\right)=\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac i{\sqrt2}$ and $\exp\left(-\frac{3\pi i}4\right)=\cos\left(-\frac{3\pi i}4\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac{3\pi i}4\right)=-\frac1{\sqrt2}-\frac i{\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact $$\text{Rez}(f,z_0)+\text{Rez}(f,z_1){={1\over 4}\left(e^{-i{\pi\over 4}}+e^{-i{3\pi\over 4}}\right)\\={1\over 4}(-\sqrt 2i)}$$therefore$$2\pi i\cdot [\text{Rez}(f,z_0)+\text{Rez}(f,z_1)]={\sqrt 2\pi \over 2}$$which is **pure** real.